# Sencha Touch 2: no local json data shown on Android device -- in dev is all OK

Tags: android, json, sencha-touch-2

for hours I am trying to find a soultion for this problem, may be some one of you has an idea or hint.

I have a data store for a nestedList which works perfectly well in my development environment but after packing a native package for android 4.2.2 I do not see any data in my app. Everything else of the app works..

This is my data store.

```
Ext.define('akApp.store.Parameter_local', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                },  

    config: {
        model: 'akApp.model.Parameter',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/dev/akApp/app/data/dvs-tab.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items',
                noCache: false,
                enablePagingParams: false
            }    
        }    
    }
 });
```

I have build my packeg with these commands:

```
sencha --debug app build production
sencha --debug app package run packager.json
```

Here is my packager.json

```
{
    "applicationName":"akApp",
       "applicationId":"de.akazia.ak",
    "bundleSeedId":"xxxxx",
    "versionString":"1.0.1",
    "versionCode":"1",
        "icon": {
                "36":"resources/icons/ic_akLogo36.png",
                "48":"resources/icons/ic_akLogo48.png",
                "72":"resources/icons/ic_akLogo72.png"
    },
    "inputPath":"./",
    "outputPath":"../build",
    "configuration":"Debug",
    "platform":"Android",
    "deviceType":"Universal",
        "certificatePath":"/home/mi01/Workspace/akApp",
    "certificateAlias":"xxxxx",
    "certificatePassword":"xxxxxx",
    "provisionProfile":"",
    "notificationConfiguration":"",
        "sdkPath":"/home/mi01/apps/adt-bundle-linux/sdk",
    "androidAPILevel":"17",
    "permissions":[
            "INTERNET",
            "VIBRATE"
        ],
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",
        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

Since I am really stuck at this point I hope for a hint. By the way I have the same issue when I use the Android Emulator.

Thanks a lot
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy json file to ..\yourapp\resources\data (create if not exist)

add 'resources/data' in uou app.json:

```
"resources": [
        "resources/images",
        "resources/icons",
        "resources/startup",
        "resources/data"
    ],
```

Try it on your device, to me works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You load the data from a file, so that in development Sencha finds it.
But in production you did not copy the json to 'build/production/xxx/dev/akApp/app/data/dvs-tab.json'

It can't be found by Sencha until you copy the data by hand or add it to:

```
app.json -> "resources": []
```

Comment: Hello 

this is stange.. 

in the native package I find the the data under this path (no change made to the current config) Since I point the store to /dev/... this can not fit

.../Workspace/build/akApp.apk_FILES/assets/app/data/dvs-tab.json

But How can I resolve this? Do I need to change the path for the data store or do I need to add something to the app.js  or packager.json

Thanks a to for any hint in the meantime i will try and hope.. :-)

Michael

Comment: inside the app.json (my bad I meant this in the example) you add the file (including the directory) to "resources". That should do it. That way everything gets copied to the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt load my json from an app generated by

```
sencha app build native
```

until I add the directory holding my json files to the resources array in app.json, like:

```
"resources": [
        "resources/images",
        "resources/icons",
        "resources/startup",
        "resources/data"
    ],
```